# IdentityServer - sign in by choosing between multiple emails or telephone numer?

Tags: asp.net, identityserver3, identityserver4

We have an ASP.NET application, and we now want to create a REST API on it. 
IdentityServer looks great for our business need.
We use ASPNETUsers in DB and our current system, which by our research should work fine by letting IdentityServer use this data.
Three questions:

1. BUT we allow our users to sign in with both their email and telephone number. Is this possible to integrate this with IdentityServer?
2. We also plan on letting users add as many emails as they like. We add these emails in a separate DB-table.
   Is it possible to also sign in using these emails using IdentityServer? (will it be a problem if the emails are not in the aspnetUser-DB-table?) 
   If this is not possible, we could just put the emails in the user-table but that is not preferred)
3. The best thing would be if we could customise everything here. IdentityServer gets a users password and username. Then we can make custom code that gets the used username, and then pass it along to IdentityServer to make the authentication and handle the process further. Might be a bit too much to ask for? :)

Answer (score 0):

The server is largely irrelevant to this question.
The client (relying party) needs to implement all of the appropriate provider configurations. The Microsoft sample code will do this by default for non-dynamic registration. Dynamic registration bring in a whole new can of worms.
I know that OpenID MODRNA is working on a protocol for telephone authn. Not sure how far out that might be.